# How can I update a database record using migration in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have 100 records in the database, each record has a `value` field that is equal to `0`

How can I use migration to change the value of the value field so that this value is in the reverse order? For example, like this: `-1, -2, -3, -4 ...`

Comment: That’s not a migration, you require an update statement of some kind.

Comment: This like a Job, not migration

Comment: For new entries: you can use a Seeder for this and for existing values you can write an job.

Answer (score 0):

Make a migration and set in the up method your query e.g like this ( untested ) :

```
 /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
       foreach(YourModel::all() as $key => $value) {
          $value->value = ++$key * (-1)
          $value->save();
       }
    }
```